# Java and Scene Builder How to Disable and Enable Tab

Tags: java, scenebuilder

I'm building an application using NetBeans and Scene Builder. I've got a TabPane, however, I wish to disable the 3rd tab in the pane when the `btnAnonymousClientClick` is clicked, how would I go about doing so?

My Code:

```
public class FXMLDocumentController implements Initializable {
    @FXML
    private Button btnCreateAnonymousClient;
    @FXML
    private Button btnCancel;
    @FXML
    private TextField txtAnonymousClientFirstName;
    @FXML
    private Label lblFirstName;
    @FXML
    private Label lbl;
    @FXML
    private TabPane tabControlPane;

    /**
     * Initializes the controller class.
     */
    @Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
        // TODO
    }    

    @FXML
    private void btnAnonymousClientClick(ActionEvent event) {

    }

    @FXML
    private void btnAnonymousClientCancel(ActionEvent event) {

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can disable a Tab by adding a fx:id to it and adding it to your code.

```
@FXML
private Tab yourTabFXID


yourTabFXID.setDisable(true);
```

Comment: Could you also capture the tabPanel and disable the tab by index?

Comment: You can do that like this `tabControlPane.getTabs().get(2).setDisable(true);`